# Redirect on saving term at custom taxnomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, redirect

Is it possible to redirect to the just created taxonomy term after hitting the Add category button?
Because it's an Ajax call im not sure!
Tried different things but didn't wor.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It can be done. Do you want to redirect to the just created term in the front end or backend?

Comment: Well, one thing I do know is that there's [no hook](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-admin/edit-tags.php#L71) for it. There's [`redirect_term_location`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/redirect_term_location/) but only applies to non-ajaxy calls. This will probably have to be a javascript solution.

Comment: Hi Codiiv, on the backend, because i created my own term meta's, i wan to either reload the page or redirect to the edit screen of the just created term.